# Non-interactive login (cached credentials) against Azure Graph API on iOS

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am creating an app on iOS that will run in a "kiosk" mode.  Part of the application requires users to be able to search an organisation's directory.  I would like to support Azure AD via the Azure Graph API to provide this function.

I don't want to require an interactive login when the app starts and I don't want to have to use an additional web service; I would like for the iOS app to simply access the Azure Graph API via REST.

I am aware of the risks associated with cached credentials, however the use of "service accounts" for non-interactive logins is fairly well established, the access is read-only and the credentials can be secured in the iOS keychain.

I have looked through numerous Azure samples and read the documentation and it seems that the method that provides what I need [`acquireToken(resource, credential)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479466.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) isn't available in the iOS ADAL library (and either is the `ClientCredential` class).

To clarify, this is how I would like my app to work:

1. User installs the app from the app store and runs it the first time
2. As part of the setup they authenticate to Azure AD by providing their tenant,  application client ID and an application key.  If they can't authenticate with an application key, a user id/password is acceptable as long as:
3. They never get prompted to authenticate again

Is there a solution here or do I just give up on Azure AD?

Comment: There is no concept of service accounts on iOS. Bringing windows artifacts and definition to iOS seems extrapolating.

Comment: Also, what is the issue with accessing graph from your app with interactive login? All you would need to do is get token for graph as a resource and use your public client Id.

Comment: I was just using that to explain the concept. The "service account" would be *used* by the iOS app.  It would exist in the Azure AD (Or preferably it would be an Azure AD application definition which has a client ID and a key rather than a username and a password).

Comment: @KanishkPanwar-MSFT Can you point at some sample code that shows how to do that?  If there can be some sort of login process that the client uses when they first install the app then that may be OK, but I don't want the login prompt to show each time the app starts; I just want to hold the token securely in the iOS keychain.

Comment: Are you using xamarin or obj-c adal library

Comment: Objective-C library

Comment: Library provides keychain token storage by default. I will post a psuedo code example when I get back home.

Comment: I have put together a quick test app - https://github.com/paulw11/GraphAPITest - I can log in, and when I log in subsequently it doesn't prompt me as the token is held in the keychain, but will that token eventually expire?

Comment: In 1 hour. But the refresh token will be used to get a new token in that case.

Comment: But how many times can the token be refreshed before the user needs to authenticate again?  What if the app isn't running and the token isn't refreshed for some period?

Comment: Refresh token will expire if not used for 14 days. It is valid up to a total of 90 days.

Comment: So that is my problem. I want the app to be able to reauthenticate without user interaction in that case but it doesn't seem possible

Comment: Using your approach, If your client secret is stolen via MITM attack then you will have to update your secret, break all the users of your app and deploy a new app. If you use the recommended approach then the compromised user would simply need to update his/her password.

Comment: User passwords can expire as well. Also some tenants may be using MFA and it would require a web UI.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I referred to the "service account" style of account; this is routinely used and the account has no password expiration or MFA. There is no "application user" per se. This is a kiosk sitting at a reception desk. It just needs to work. The access is low risk since it is just reading basic user information from the directory.  An azure AD web app already supports this through the use of a client key rather than a user credential.  It seems that the answer is not to use Azure AD, which is annoying. This style of authentication is supported by native Windows apps

Comment: I am not sure if using anything else that implements oauth would help either. I would recommend that you reconsider your app scenario. Say for example, you are a gym where people sign in at the kiosk. The app should be able to pull user info from graph and create attendance record in your DB. For this, the gym owner/manager can sign in to kiosk and have people use it then..... Just throwing ideas. :)

Comment: I am playing around with NXOAuth2, which at least has a method that accepts a username & password, but it doesn't seem to work either, but to explore your gym scenario; Say the manager logs in; 90 days later the kiosk stops working and users are unable to sign in, so the manager has to sign in again, or the manager leaves and the account is invalidated; again the kiosks stop working and someone has to fix it.  Or a "shared account" is used and all the managers need to know it so that they can re-login.  All of this is worse than secure credentials stored in the app.

Comment: I have worked it out. I will add an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but not with the ADALiOS framework as it doesn't expose the `client_credentials` grant that is required to make it work.

I was able to build a working demonstration using [p2/OAuth](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2).  The sample app is [here](https://github.com/paulw11/GraphAPITest)

The steps to build a working solution are:

1. Login to the legacy [Azure Management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) and select your Azure AD Instance
2. Create a new application in that AD instance

   1. Select "Add an application my organisation is developing"
   2. Give it a name and select "Web application and/or Web API" **not** "Native Client Application"
   3. Enter values for sign on url and app id url.  These need to be well-formed URLs but do not need to be reachable
3. Once the application has been created select "Configure".  Note the *Client ID* - you will need this
4. In the "Keys" selection, select 1 or 2 years from the drop down, then click "Save"
5. Once the key is displayed, copy this and save it somewhere; it can't be displayed again.
6. Set the required "Permissions to other applications" to allow your app the access it needs
7. Finally, at the bottom of the screen click "view endpoints" - You need to copy the OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint and the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint
8. Download the demo code from GitHub
9. Run `pod install`
10. Plug the values into the `Settings.plist` file
11. Run the app

The meat of the authentication process is to set up an instance of `OAuth2ClientCredentials` -

```
let settings = [
        "client_id": appData.clientId!,
        "client_secret": appData.secret!,
        "authorize_uri": appData.authString!,
        "token_uri": appData.tokenString!,
        "keychain": true,
        "secret_in_body": true
        ] as OAuth2JSON

self.oauth2 = OAuth2ClientCredentials(settings: settings)
```

Then you can call `doAuthorize()` to get a token

```
self.oauth2.doAuthorize()
```